# refined equation numbering using other chapter title

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, conditionals

I would like to use book class and number equation in that way:

The equation have to carry just number of equation *without*
    chapter number. I get this using

```
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
```

Then when using `\ref` command i would like that

1. if the `\ref` is invoked in the same chapter of equation the reference is just `(equation)`
2. if `\ref` is invoked in another chapter of the equation the reference to be `(equation)\textsubscript{name-of-the-chapter-containing-equation}`

Here there is my attempt using `zref`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\thechapter}
\zref@addprop{main}{chapter}
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\ifnum\thechapter=\zref[chapter]{#1} (\zref{#1}) \else (\zref{#1})\textsubscript{something} \fi}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{First}
 \ifnum\myref[chapter]{eq:1}=1 a \else b \fi
  \myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
 \section{First First}
 \begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:1}
 E=\gamma m
 \end{equation}
 \section{First Second}
 \begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:2}
 0=0
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Second}
  \myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
 \begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:3}
 e^{i\pi}+1=0
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Third}
  \myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
 \begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:4}
 f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Last}
 \myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\end{document}
```

I have two problems in the definition of `\myref`

1. `\ifnum` does not work properly because maybe `\zref[chapter]{#1}` does not return a number and so it's impossible to compare with `\thechapter'
2. I have to find a command to get the chapter name corresponding to a number (or perhaps to use `\nameref`)

How can I solve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows.  First use the `\zrefused` and `\zref@extract` to get the value to compare to trigger the extra formatting.

Now the package `zref-titleref` gives you the idea of how to get the title field, but it updates not just at chapters but also at sections etc.  So instead we write a modified version of the `zref-titleref` code, that just grabs chapter titles.

[image: Sample output]
[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-user,gettitlestring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\setcurrentchaptername}[1]{\GetTitleStringNonExpand{#1}\edef\currentchaptername{\detokenize\expandafter{\GetTitleStringResult}}}
\def\currentchaptername{}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\thechapter}
\zref@addprop{main}{chapter}
\zref@newprop{chaptername}{\currentchaptername}
\zref@addprop{main}{chaptername}
\ZREF@patch{@chapter}{\def\@chapter[#1]{\setcurrentchaptername{#1}%
  \ZREF@org@@chapter[{#1}]}}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\zrefused{#1}%
\ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{chapter}=\thechapter\relax
(\zref{#1}) \else (\zref{#1})\textsubscript{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptername}}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\section{First First}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:1}
  E=\gamma m
\end{equation}
\section{First Second}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:2}
  0=0
\end{equation}
\chapter{Second}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:3}
  e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\chapter{Third}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:4}
  f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
\end{equation}
\chapter{Last}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\end{document}
```

As in your code, `\zref@newprop` is used to set-up new properties to track.  These need to have a way to grab the correct data at the time the `\zlabel` command is called.  For the chapter number this is in `\thechapter`, which you already used.  For the chapter title, we store this in `\currentchaptername` and modify the `\chapter` command so that this name is set.  If you wish to use a different (e.g. shorter) name, then you can redefine `\currentchaptername` immediately after the `\chapter` command.  Now in the referencing command `\myref`, we get the label data by first issuing `\zrefused` and then `\zref@extract` to get a particular field.

I have changed your relative numbering of equations to be within `chapter`s rather than `section`s, otherwise you will get duplicate labels.  If you really wanting resetting at each section, then you should also be referencing the relevant section title instead, and could probably use `zref-titleref` directly.

The above code only grabs titles of numbered chapters.  You can apply a similar patch to `\chapter*` via `@schapter` if you wish, or alternatively set `\currentchatpername` directly yourself in such circumstances.

Comment: I discovered a very strange issue: if I use `multline` instead of `equation` environment I get some error message. Other env. like `eqnarray` work perfectly. I cannot understand why. Can you?

Comment: Yes, `zlabel` has all sorts of issues in ams environments which play with fundamentals of the label mechanism. In the `multline` it does not write any information to the `.aux` file.  You could work around by using `multlined` from `mathtools` inside an `equation`, but that is not satisfactory.  Perhaps you should ask a new question asking how to get `zref` to work with the ams environments.