# zref an amsmath envirnonment

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, zref

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365700/refined-equation-numbering-using-other-chapter-title/365743?noredirect=1#comment915033_365743) I asked a specific question about `zref` package. The answer is very satisfactory, but unfortunately I noticed that, for example `zref` is not workin with some ams envirnomnent such as `multline`, more specifically:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-user,gettitlestring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\setcurrentchaptername}[1]{\GetTitleStringNonExpand{#1}\edef\currentchaptername{\detokenize\expandafter{\GetTitleStringResult}}}
\def\currentchaptername{}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapter}{\thechapter}
\zref@addprop{main}{chapter}
\zref@newprop{chaptername}{\currentchaptername}
\zref@addprop{main}{chaptername}
\ZREF@patch{@chapter}{\def\@chapter[#1]{\setcurrentchaptername{#1}%
  \ZREF@org@@chapter[{#1}]}}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\zrefused{#1}%
\ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{chapter}=\thechapter\relax
(\zref{#1}) \else (\zref{#1})\textsubscript{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptername}}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\section{First First}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:1}
  E=\gamma m
\end{equation}
\section{First Second}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:2}
  0=0
\end{equation}
\chapter{Second}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:3}
  e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
\chapter{Third}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\begin{equation}\zlabel{eq:4}
  f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
\end{equation}
\chapter{Last}
\myref{eq:1}, \myref{eq:2}, \myref{eq:3}, \myref{eq:4}
\end{document}
```

works perfectly and it is exactly what I wanted, but if I substitute `equation` environment with `multline`, it doesn't compile. I know that there are some issues about `.aux` file.
Is there a way to make `zref` and `multline` works simultaneously? I know that one can replace `multline` by similar environment, but I was looking for some modified reference system that works well in all situation.

Comment: The MWE does not compile.  Was that your intent?

Comment: It does, at least in my PCs, if you copy and paste the above MWE.

Comment: If I push through all the errors, it eventually compiles.  Then, subsequent passes compile without issue.  Try deleting your `aux` file and recompile to see what I mean.

Comment: You have to compile it a second time, the it will proceed without errors.

Comment: compiling a second time without addressing the errors reported from the first compile isn't a generally robust approach.  the fact that you can't get an error-free first compile indicates a structural problem.

Comment: The issue with the first compilation can easiliy be solved: use `\zref@newprop{chapter}{\arabic{chapter}}` and `\ifnum\zref@extractdefault{#1}{chapter}{0}=\arabic{chapter}\relax`. (This won't resolve the issue with `multline`, though)